# How can I convert a text file into a list of int arrays

Tags: c#, arraylist, text-files

I have a text file containing the following content:

```
0 0 1 0 3 
0 0 1 1 3 
0 0 1 2 3 
0 0 3 0 1 
0 0 0 1 2 1 1 
0 0 1 0 3 
0 0 1 1 3 
0 0 1 2 3 
0 0 3 0 1 
0 0 1 2 3 
0 0 3 0 1
```

There are no spaces between the rows but there is a space between the numbers. I want to read these integers from a txt file and save in a list of int arrays in C#.

Comment: How are the rows separated? Any newline? Or rather is a single long array of numbers, which is visually wrapped by the editor?

Comment: the txt file look like this exactly there is a no. of row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileToIntList
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Read the file as one string.
        System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\M.M.S.I\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();

        myFile.Close();

        // Display the file contents.
        //Console.WriteLine(myString);
        char rc = (char)10;
        String[] listLines = myString.Split(rc);
        List<List<int>> listArrays = new List<List<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listLines.Length; i++)
        {
            List<int> array = new List<int>();
            String[] listInts = listLines[i].Split(' ');
            for(int j=0;j<listInts.Length;j++)
            {
                if (listInts[j] != "\r")
                {
                    array.Add(Convert.ToInt32(listInts[j]));
                }
            }
            listArrays.Add(array);
        }


        foreach(List<int> array in listArrays){
            foreach (int i in array)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
}
```

Comment: The lines are in the listArrays, every element of listArrays is a line of your text file.

Comment: sorry for taking your time but i need help ,i want this result list{[0,0,1,0,3][0,0,1,1,3]} List<int>[] output

Comment: @user2680386 this will read the whole file into memory, which is not a good idea if the file is very large.

Comment: this program returns the result list you want, it's a list of int Lists

Comment: this is my first time to programming in c# so i have difficulties in my project

Comment: ok i will explaint it to you, every line of yout text file is an element of listArrays, if you want to select line number 3 :
    `List<int> arrayNumber3 = listArrays.ElementAt<List<int>>(3);`
To browse all lines elements :
    `foreach(List<int> array in listArrays){
            foreach (int i in array)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }`
array will contain the current line of listArrays(wich contains all the lines).
i will contain the current int of the selected line wich is array.

Comment: Thank you very much,it's work exactly like what i want

Comment: your are welcome my friend, you can check my awnser to show to stackoverflow that it helped you ;) thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your string is called text, and contains "1 1 1 0 3 2 3" etc.
You declare a string array.

```
String[] numbers1=text.Split(" ");
```

Now declare your int array and convert each one to int.

```
int[] numbers2=new int[numbers.Length];
for(int i=0; i<numbers.Length; i++)
    numbers2[i]=Convert.ToInt32(numbers1[i]);
```

And you're done.

Comment: All this can be one in one line `int[] arr= text.Split(' ').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();`. And no overload method for Split accept only string parameter. It should be character.

Comment: Didnt get u, what so u mean by take time, how much time?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var numbers =
    System.IO.File
        .ReadAllLines(@"C:\text.txt")
        .Select(x => x.Split(' ')
            .Select(y => int.Parse(y))
            .ToArray())
        .ToList();
```

I get this result:

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultList = new List<int>();
File.ReadAllLines("filepath") 
    .ToList()
    .ForEach((line) => {
                            var numbers = line.Split()
                                              .Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c));
                            resultList.AddRange(numbers); 
                        });
```

Comment: There is no overload of Split() that takes zero arguments.

Comment: @phoog, you are wrong.Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx, `If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters.`

Comment: @Selman22 of course.  I forgot that the argument to the Split(char[]) overload is a `params` array.  But I note that after I wrote my comment you changed `c => (int)c` (which was a compile error) into the Convert.ToInt32 call.  Perhaps more importantly, thw whole thing sould be more concise if you used `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

string filePath = @"D:\Path\To\The\File.txt";
List<int[]> listOfArrays =
    File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(line => line.Split(' ').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Since you mention that it is your first time programming in C#, this version may be easier to understand; the process is the same as the above:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

string filePath = @"D:\Path\To\The\File.txt";

IEnumerable<string> linesFromFile = File.ReadLines(path);

Func<string, int[]> convertStringToIntArray =
    line => {
        var stringArray = line.Split(' ');
        var intSequence = stringArray.Select(s => int.Parse(s)); // or ....Select(Convert.ToInt32);
        var intArray = intSequance.ToArray();
        return intArray;
    };

IEnumerable<int[]> sequenceOfIntArrays = linesFromFile.Select(convertStringToIntArray);

List<int[]> listOfInfArrays = sequenceOfIntArrays.ToList();
```

Comment: Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. C:\C#\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs 27 21 ConsoleApplication4
i have this error