# Converting text file into list of int array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, int, text-files

I have a text file containing the following content:

```
63795
765
23780
16935
73358
12982
73530
14494
77439
13646
```

I've seen this thread:
[how i can convert text file into list of int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347879/how-i-can-convert-text-file-into-list-of-int-array)

But I am wondering if there is an easier way of doing it for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there it is:

```
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(theFilePath);

int[] theValues = data.Select(d => int.Parse(d)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Uh.. Here's what happened: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrPpQv8qshI&feature=youtu.be - What am I doing wrong? I'm a beginner at C#, sorry if I may appear dumb

Comment: Yes, you have done a Console.WriteLine to an array, it will output the array type, if you want to show the content iterate with a for or foreach loop over it and write the values.

Comment: How silly of me, I forgot about the for/foreach part when writing a list. thank you for the help, it works fine now! :)