# Converting Text File into a List <int> (C#)

Tags: c#, string, arraylist, text-files

I am using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347879/how-i-can-convert-text-file-into-list-of-int-array) for a starting point. I am completely new to C#, but have experience in C/C++. My goal is to recreate sorting algorithms and have them race each other using forking. I have successfully recreated the mergesort, bubble, and insertion, and plan on implemented quicksort as well.

I created a separate class that creates a file of 100,000 random integers to properly test out the speed of the sorting algorithms.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\pathtofile\randomNumbers.txt");

int count = 0;
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber;
int lines = 0;
while (count++ < 100000)
{
    randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 250);
    sw.Write(randomNumber);
    sw.Write(" "); // create white space
    if(lines == 25) //formatting
    {
        sw.WriteLine("");
        lines = 0;
    }
    lines++;
}
```

The error that I am getting from my main class that stores these integers into an array list is failing at this point:

```
lists.Add(Convert.ToInt32(listInts[j]));
```

> //ERROR: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct
>   format.'

From what I can tell is when it is converting the integers, it grabs a value that isn't an integer and fails. However, the confusing part for me is when I manually type in the integers It works just fine.

EX: 134 0 13 42 232 48 424 166 109

Any help would be appreciative.

C#Nooby

Comment: [Use your debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) to look at the value of `listInts[j]`. It's not an integer.

Comment: The code you showed is incomplete, provide a n MCVE or at least show more code, specifically the part where you read from the file, since in the one you showed it could be writing to either a file or standard console output (what is `sw`)?

Comment: Sorry, new to the formatting to this website. The brackets cut off a line of code. I editted now.

Comment: Without you showing the read code the best I can say is that you should mind line breaks when reading and to also split your read line by the `' '` (space) token and note that the last element of the returned array might have "\n" appended at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned by [vetzascoa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10312254/vetzascoa) and [Stas Ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4393579/stas-ivanov), the exception in your code might be caused by the non-handled whitespaces and empty strings.

To solve this issue, you can modify your method for writing the test data to a file as follows:

```cs
static string Delimiter => " ";
static string LineBreak => "\r\n";

static void WriteTestFile(string fileName,
    int dataLength = 100000,
    int dataMinvalue = 1,
    int dataMaxValue = 250,
    int lineBreakPosition = 25)
{
    int iterator = 0;
    string delimiter;

    Random rndGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNumber;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        while (iterator < dataLength)
        {
            randomNumber = rndGenerator.Next(dataMinvalue, dataMaxValue);
            delimiter = ++iterator % lineBreakPosition == 0 ? LineBreak : Delimiter;
            streamWriter.Write($"{randomNumber}{delimiter}");
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, you can avoid redundant whitespaces at the end of each line. Also, **note** that `FileStream`, `StreamReader`, and `StreamWriter` are `IDisposable` objects. Therefore, they [should be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) within either `using(...)` or `try/finally` blocks.

To read the file and transform its contents into a `List<int>`, you can use the following code:

```cs
static List<int> ReadTestFile(string fileName)
{
    string fileContents;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        fileContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var separators = string.Join("", LineBreak, Delimiter).ToCharArray();
    var query = from item in fileContents
                 .Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)                        
                 select int.Parse(item);

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Splitting the file contents string with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option will [exclude empty entries/substrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.8) generated by the `String.Split` method. This will ensure error-free string-to-int conversion.

Below, you can find a complete minimal working solution to your problem.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FileToListInt
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly string filePath = "randomNumbers.txt";

        static string Delimiter => " ";
        static string LineBreak => "\r\n";

        static void WriteTestFile(string fileName,
            int dataLength = 100000,
            int dataMinvalue = 1,
            int dataMaxValue = 250,
            int lineBreakPosition = 25)
        {
            int iterator = 0;
            string delimiter;

            Random rndGenerator = new Random();
            int randomNumber;

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                while (iterator < dataLength)
                {
                    randomNumber = rndGenerator.Next(dataMinvalue, dataMaxValue);
                    delimiter = ++iterator % lineBreakPosition == 0 ? LineBreak : Delimiter;
                    streamWriter.Write($"{randomNumber}{delimiter}");
                }
            }
        }

        static List<int> ReadTestFile(string fileName)
        {
            string fileContents;

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                fileContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var separators = string.Join("", LineBreak, Delimiter).ToCharArray();
            var query = from item in fileContents
                         .Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)                        
                         select int.Parse(item);

            return query.ToList();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Writing data to a test file
            WriteTestFile(filePath);

            // Reading result into a List<int>
            List<int> data = ReadTestFile(filePath);

            // Checking the number of readings
            Console.WriteLine(data.Count);

            // Deleting test file
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, thanks to everyone as well. I wasn't expecting this fast of a response.

I will have to sift through all of these methods calls you have listed here because a few of them I don't know what they do and why. But this gives me a good foundation for learning C#.

Also, this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that it worked for you. I would appreciate if you mark this solution as the accepted answer. Should you have any questions to method calls/logic, just ask them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error you are getting, it seems to me you are not taking into account line breaks (at least I was able to reproduce it on my side this way).

This is how it worked for me with a file which contained new lines (I used an overload of *Split* which accepts an array of chars to split by, additionally it'll ignore empty entries because of provided *StringSplitOptions*):

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt"))
{       
    var text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();       
    var numbers = text.Split(new [] {' ', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(word => Convert.ToInt32(word));
    // do something with numbers (IEnumerable<Int32>)
}
```

The code above stores the numbers into a *IEnumerable* collection. In case you need an array, you should call *ToArray()*.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you two solutions. 
One of them is modifying the code you're using to create the file with the numbers.
The other one is modifying the code you're using from the link you tell us.

The problem in your code is inside the while loop, when you write to the file the white space:

```
randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 250);
sw.Write(randomNumber);
sw.Write(" "); // create white space  <------ this line
```

This line is writing an space always after a number. That means your file will end with and empty space instead a number. This causes a exception in the line

```
lists.Add(Convert.ToInt32(listInts[j]));
```

because for the last line in the file generated listInts[j] = " ".

**First possible solution**

When you're gonna write an empty space to the file, do it only if isn't after write the last number.
Your while loop should look similar to this:

```
while (count++ < 100000)
{
    randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 250);
    sw.Write(randomNumber);
    if (count < 100000) //avoid write a white space if is last number to write
    {
        sw.Write(" "); // create white space
    }
    if(lines == 25) //formatting
    {
        sw.WriteLine("");
        lines = 0;
    }
    lines++;
}
```

**Second possible solution**

In the code you're using to read the file, just remove empty white spaces from each line before split into an array using function .Trim()

```
String[] listInts = listLines[i].Trim().Split(' ');
```

instead of current line

```
String[] listInts = listLines[i].Split(' ');
```